# Pytorch's packed_sequence/pad_sequence pads tensors vertically for list of tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm

I am trying to pad sequence of tensors for LSTM mini-batching, where each timestep in the sequence contains a sub-list of tensors (representing multiple features in a single timestep).

For example, sequence 1 would have 3 timesteps and within each timestep there are 2 features. An example below would be:

Sequence 1 = [[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[3,2],[3,2]]

Sequence 2 = [[4,2],[5,1],[4,4]]

Sequence 3 = [[6,9]]

I run pytorch's pad_sequence function (this goes for pack_sequence too) like below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.utils.rnn as rnn_utils

a = torch.tensor([[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[3,2],[3,2]])
b = torch.tensor([[4,2],[5,1],[4,4]])
c = torch.tensor([[6,9]])
result = rnn_utils.pad_sequence([a, b, c])
```

My expected output is as follows:

Sequence 1 = [[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[3,2],[3,2]]

Sequence 2 = [[4,2],[5,1],[4,4],[0,0],[0,0]]

Sequence 3 = [[6,9],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]

However, the output I got is as follows:

```
tensor([[[1, 2],
         [4, 2],
         [6, 9]],

        [[2, 2],
         [5, 1],
         [0, 0]],

        [[3, 3],
         [4, 4],
         [0, 0]],

        [[3, 2],
         [0, 0],
         [0, 0]],

        [[3, 2],
         [0, 0],
         [0, 0]]])
```

The padding seems to go vertically rather than what I expect. How do I go about getting the correct padding that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change

```
result = rnn_utils.pad_sequence([a, b, c])
```

to

```
result = rnn_utils.pad_sequence([a, b, c], batch_first=True)
seq1 = result[0]
seq2 = result[1]
seq3 = result[2]
```

By default, `batch_first` is False. Output will be in `B x T x *` if True, or in `T x B x *` otherwise, where

`B` is batch size. It is equal to the number of elements in `sequences`,

`T` is length of the longest sequence, and

`*` is any number of trailing dimensions, including none.

**output:**

```
tensor([[1, 2],
        [2, 2],
        [3, 3],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 2]]) # sequence 1
tensor([[4, 2],
        [5, 1],
        [4, 4],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]]) # sequence 2
tensor([[6, 9],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]]) # sequence 3
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a hero! I noticed that pack_sequence does not have a batch_first = True option. Is there an analogy to what I should do if I wanted to use pack_sequence?

Comment: I am glad I could help you. This function returns a Tensor of size T x B x * or  B x T x * based on the value of "batch_first" attribute. Check what T, B and * means above.There is also a "padding_value" which is 0 by default. You can change that as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks. when I run rnn_utils.pack_padded_sequence(x,torch.tensor([5,3,1]),batch_first=True) on the example above, I get that my batch sizes are the following: batch_sizes=tensor([3, 2, 2, 1, 1])). But I am expecting [5,3,1] instead. What went wrong?

Comment: Here batch_sizes=tensor([3, 2, 2, 1, 1]) represents grouping "[[1,2], [4, 2], [6,9]]", "[[2, 2], [5, 1]]", "[[3, 3]]", "[[4, 4]]", "[[3, 2]]" and "[[3, 2]]" respectively.